# cheeriojs iterate over xml response

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cheerio, queryselector

Say I have an xml response from a request that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xsl/someExcelSheet.xsl"?>
<events>
  <event onair="true">
    <type>Live</type>
    <title>Nyhederne - 1/1</title>
    <airtime>09:30:02.13</airtime>
    <id>58529</id>
  </event>
  <event onair="false">
    <type>PrimaryVideo</type>
    <title>MTV1</title>
    <airtime>09:35:02.13</airtime>
    <id>58532</id>
  </event>
  ...
```

How do I use `cheeriojs` to extract data from it?

Was doing

```js
  request(url, (error, response, xml) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(xml, {
        xmlMode: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        withStartIndices: false,
        withEndIndices: false,
      })
```

and trying

```sh
> $('events')
LoadedCheerio(1) [Element, options: {…}, _root: LoadedCheerio(1), prevObject: LoadedCheerio(1)]
> $('event')
LoadedCheerio(468) [Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, Element, …]
```

but could not figure out how to work with it. Wanted to grab all `event` in the `events` and iterate over it and read the text in the `<type>`, `<title>` etc tags.

what I ended up doing was

```js
const rows: string[][] = $('event')
  .text()
  .split(/\n/)
  .map((str) => str.trim())
  .join('\n')
  .split(/\n{2,}/g)
  .reduce((acc, str) => [...acc, str.split(/\n/)], [])
```

But there must be a better way and I'm hoping somebody would like to explain that to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
$('event').get().map(event => {
  return {
    type: $(event).find('type').text(),
    title: $(event).find('title').text(),
    // more props
  }
})
```